# Is there a way to find all models that contain a GenericRelation to a particular model in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, reflection

Lets say we have the following model with a `GenericForeignKey`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    customer_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    model = GenericForeignKey()
```

And in several places it is referenced in other models:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
...
class Contract(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

Is it possible to get a list of the types that reference the Comment model? e.g. `[Contract,Invoice]` in this example?

Similar functionality is possible in for instance C# with Reflection.

I need something that will work when there are no references already, so `Comment.objects.values('content_type')` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `get_models` function of app. Here is an example:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
all_models = apps.get_models()
models_with_generic_relation = [
                                model.__name__ for model in all_models if 
                                any(
                                    isinstance(field, GenericRelation) 
                                    for field in model._meta.fields
                                )
                               ]
print(models_with_generic_relation)
```

In `models_with_generic_relation`, you will have all models having `GenericRelation`.